# Borel $\sigma$ - algebra over the space of finite functions

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I think my question is relatively trivial, although I could not find the answer anywhere!

So, while reading the article: *"Random Relations, Random Utilities, and Random Functions*,  the author, on page 18, makes this comment:

> Notice that there is a natural $\sigma$ - algebra of events to consider over the function
> space $\mathbb{R}^\mathscr{C}$, namely the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathscr{C}})$.

In the paper, we are assuming that $\mathscr{C}$ is a finite, nonempty set and, as he stated, the set $\mathbb{R}^{\mathscr{C}}$ is used as notation for the set of all functions from $\mathscr{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The questions that are left unanswered for me are

1. What is the topology he is using to construct this Borel $\sigma$ - algebra?
2. Does it have easily usable generator sets, like the $\sigma$ - algebra generated by the real numbers under the standard topology?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the set is finite, one can identify the given space with $\mathbb R^d$, no? If so, $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ is just the $\sigma$-algebra given by the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R\times\dots\times \mathbb R$

Comment: As I guess you know, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is simply the one generated by the open sets, so we just have to find the natural topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathscr{C}$. But if $|\mathscr{C}|=n$, there is a canonical isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^\mathscr{C}\cong \mathbb{R}^n$ given by the canonical basis (as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space) for $\mathbb{R}^\mathscr{C}$, $e_1,\dots, e_n$ where $e_i$ is $1$ on the $i$'th element of $\mathscr{C}$, and $0$ on all others.
Then $\mathbb{R}^\mathscr{C}$ simply inherits the usual topology.

Comment: @fKonrad  That was exactly my first thought, but I didn't really understand how to put everything together. Guess I'm super rusty in my topology concepts.  Just to be clear then, if we call $f$ the natural isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\mathscr{C}}$, then the natural topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathscr{C}}$ is simply the collection $S = \{ O \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\mathscr{C}} \, | \, f^{- 1}(O) \in \mathcal{T} \}$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence, we simply use this topology as our generating set, for the $\sigma$ - algebra.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim The comment above was intended for both you and fKonrad, but I could only tag one person. By the way, thank you both immensily. As a economics graduate studying math by myself, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: As an addendum, it would be potentially easier (and perhaps more in line with standard notation) to have the $f: \mathbb{R}^{\mathscr{C}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $S = \{ f^{-1}(O) \, | \, O \in \mathcal{T} \}$.

Comment: @GiordanoRibeiro Yes, that is correct. In your first case, $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^\mathscr{C}$, you could even define the topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathscr{C}$ to be $\lbrace f(O)\rbrace$, i.e. the images of open sets. Said in a neater way, you define the topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathscr{C}$ to be the unique topology such that the vector space isomorphism $f$ becomes a homeomorphism.